# I can't run testng.xml, getting error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, xml, selenium, jboss, testng

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrOuW.png)  is my project structure

When i am trying to run testng.xml, I am getting the below error :

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.8.2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.internal.IConfiguration.getConfigurationListeners()Ljava/util/List;
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_5$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_5.java:34)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_5$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_5.java:63)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:547)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:142)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:106)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1059)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1045)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:881)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:824)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes";"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"
```

Is this happening because of testng version conflicts? I am stuck on this since past many days.

Comment: Remove `"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"` from `environment variables` in your system. It will cause you more problems

Turn it on again if you want to use HP UFT

Answer (score 0):

On console : `detected TestNG version 6.8.2`
and in your folder structure , it is : `6.12`

You should update your TestNG jar and re-configure the latest one in your buildpath. You can download the latest from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng).

Answer (score 0):

You have to match your TestNG version install in Eclipse and your TestNG dependency.

You can't run TestNG dependency of 7.1.0 with TestNG Software 6.14 installed in your eclipse.

You can install your compatible TestNG version from [here](https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/)

Follow [these](https://www.toolsqa.com/testng/install-testng/) steps to install/upgrade TestNG version in your eclipse: